# Google Chrome handling page breaks differently on different computers

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, print-css

I am finalizing a print stylesheet for a rendered report in a web application and have been notified of some printing issues on different machines. When adding a page break before my header, I am noticing a ton of added white space, which seems tied to the page break. When I add `background-color: green`, etc. to the headers or footers of the page, the white space is clearly not due to either. My Windows 10 OS machine and a Mac OS I have as a back-up both create a print preview document that honors the page breaks as I would expect, but another machine running Windows 10 shows the added white space.

**UPDATE** - One of the machines that is experiencing the issue with page breaks is only experiencing the problem on particular WiFi connections. When connected to the WiFi at my working location, the problem seems to disappear from his machine, but when connected to the WiFi at his working location, the problem arises again. Very bizarre....

I am applying `page-break-before: always` to my header content and my website code is as follows:

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 1.3;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.page-portrait {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  position: relative;
  width: 1350px;
  min-height: 279mm;
  padding: 30mm;
  border: 1px #D3D3D3 solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.report-row-preview {
  min-height: 4cm;
}

.header {
  margin-top: 1cm;
  page-break-before: always;
}

.footer {
  margin-top: 1cm;
}

.copyright {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

@media print {
  html,
  body {
    width: 216mm;
    height: 279mm;
    background-color: white;
  }
  .page-portrait {
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin-left: 4%;
    width: 100% !important;
  }
  .no-print {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row page-portrait">
  <div class="row header">...</div>
  <div class="row report-row-preview">...</div>
  <div class="row report-row-preview">...</div>
  <div class="row report-row-preview">...</div>
  <div class="row footer">...</div>
</div>
```

Finally, here is a screenshot of the added white space that I am referring to:

[image]

Happy to provide anymore clarity as necessary, I'm just banging my head against the wall with this.

Comment: 279mm seems to be US letter? Might the browser assume A4 is the default based on something like the first visible real or virtual printer? That seems to be more or less how it worked at one point: https://support.google.com/chrome/forum/AAAAP1KN0B0wEQDDKKItY8

Comment: At any rate I would preview with A4 explicitly set and see if it reproduces the problem..

Comment: I've done previews with A4 and the problem still persists. It's so bizarre, certain WiFi connections cause the problem to go away and others cause it to show up. Could it really be something tied to the first visible printer that it sees? Even if the default chosen paper size is "Letter" when I expand More Settings under Print Preview?

Comment: Have you tried explicitly defining `@page` properties in CSS? I.e. not `html, body`. I remember they are quite crucial for certain libraries generating paged output (although they are not well supported in browsers).
https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-paged-media

Comment: @rahlf23 could you also attach screenshots for both landscape and portrait orientations? I feel the current styling that you attached is for landscape.

Comment: When connecting to different WiFi, have you checked if browser gets exactly the same HTML and CSS as from other access points? Maybe there's some cache/proxy on the way and it serves outdated code?

Comment: Try in  private mode may be css is cached.

Answer (score 0):

I can't help with the odd wifi issue... But as for consistent sizing, you should make sure that **ALL** your measurements are in **printer-friendly units**.

My guess is that you're getting extra space because each OS/Machine is interpreting `px` and `percent` differently when it goes to print.

This is especially true for `font-size` which is likely different based on how screen density is converted. Which in turn causes your `page-break` and wrapping rules to be in different places. That generates different spacing.

Try specifying `font-size` in `pt` and `width`/`margin` in `cm` or `mm`

For example you have this rule:

```
.page-portrait {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  position: relative;
  width: 1350px;
  min-height: 279mm;
  padding: 30mm;
  border: 1px #D3D3D3 solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

I would change to:

```
margin-top: 1cm;
margin-bottom: 1cm;
width: 210mm;
```

Also `font-size: 10px` probably translates to `font-size: 8pt` but you'll need to play with that sizing to get it correct.

Comment: Its not css issue It is the rendering of some part of css which does not work when on particular wifi.

Comment: @JinThakur Unless you're the one experiencing the issue, you can't make the statement that one thing or another *specifically ISN'T* the problem.

Comment: Bryce Howitson its mentioned in problem. and I have see in my company that switching network can change website behavior. quote from the OP UPDATE - One of the machines that is experiencing the issue with page breaks is only experiencing the problem on particular WiFi connections. When connected to the WiFi at my working location, the problem seems to disappear from his machine, but when connected to the WiFi at his working location, the problem arises again. Very bizarre.

Comment: @JinThakur Yes the OP said **ONE** of the machines. Often the symptoms we see are the result of compound problems. The fact remains, only the OP can say if something is or isn't a solution.

Comment: @BryceHowitson thank you for your answer. Just back into the office so let me play around with this and get back with you.

Comment: @rahlf23 Of course! This probably won't solve the entire issue but at least it will normalize things across platforms to hopefully give you direction on the network issues.

Answer (score 0):

One reason could be that the machines have different zoom settings, for example, laptops often have 125% zoom, which affects the browser.  The way to handle it would be to make it look good in 125% zoom and then you wind up with a bit of space on 100% zoom, but you'll see a lot of sites already work like this.

Comment: Window zoom should not affect how PRINT CSS is applied. However @rahlf23 I would recommend that this `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">` is in your HTML header

Comment: Physically looking at the monitor, it absolutely affects how a website is displayed, however since this answer the wifi piece seems more of the issue, so... relative vs absolute pathing dns resolution problem?

Comment: Yes but the question is about print css. Zoom won't cause the extra space Noted I'm the screenshot of the OS print preview.

Answer (score -2):

You have to learn how to add css so that it works on both WiFi network. Make sure you add your css in relative form.

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">`
 and not http://acx/we.css.
Make sure it is internal css. Sometime when you use external css and you have different connection WiFi and LAN your company security changes. So based on path company might block css.
Check traffic log under network in Developer tools in Chrome.Check for 401.check css getting overridden also under elements in Chrome developer tools.

Comment: Where did you get the impression that he "[has] to learn how to add css"?

Comment: Css is getting blocked in one of WIFI network . Some companies block external url non https url . Sometime  making relative path helps. I am working for a law firm and we see these issue all the time. Some time even windows authentication can create issue based on path.

Comment: @ Cameron Hurd Have you ever seen unsigned fonts getting blocked because of companies private security fire wall? People Working in small company with little or less security will never witness those issues.

Comment: His screenshots indicate that the stylesheet has loaded and is being applied.

Comment: Do you see 2 screenshots or 3 one with different wifi and one with another non working wifi?